# Phrase or one word request for 'Bitch pass'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to say that some people are allowed to be mean and rude, because we know the struggles they are temporarily going through and we are willing to put up with the drama for their sake. Put crudely, we give them a 'bitch pass'.

Is there an alternative way of phrasing this that doesn't depend on insults or vulgar terms?

Comment: I actually kinda like "bitch pass" and will probably start using it all the time now. :P

Comment: This is typically phrased simply "they get a pass".

Comment: You could say that the person deserves *extra tolerance* during that difficult time, perhaps

Comment: In all fairness we should probably stop giving people leeway for being enormous douchebags just because they're going through some stuff. Everyone goes through stuff but some people are capable of dealing with it without becoming grade A assholes. ;)

Comment: Tim's answer sounds the best so far to me informally. A formal way would be 'to be understanding'. Except it feels like 'bitch pass' is gendered, intended for women, and it would seem a little strange being used for a man. Is this the case? Do you care if the non-offensive alternative applies to males also?

Comment: Given that OP has used both *people are allowed* and *word to describe this allowance* in the question text, I think it's worth pointing out that one of the most common non-slang usages in this area is that we may ***make allowances*** for someone's inappropriate behaviour if we know they've experienced "unusual" relevant / mitigating circumstances. But there will be dozens of different ways of saying this, within which the *exact* context may favour one over another. It's all a matter of opinion.

Comment: It seemed obvious to me that the intent, here, was to find something that would cover the same ground as "bitch pass" that did not depend on vulgarity or insult, not the obviously impossible (if taken literally) notion of a phrase that *cannot* be interpreted as offensive. If so, the answer requested is no more likely to be option based than any other phrase request. (I suggest adjusting the Q. to address that.)

Answer (score 8):

We can **cut them some slack** during a difficult time.

Answer (score 2):

Excusing shoddy behavior because we understand someone is going through difficult times is "pity" (as much as we care about their troubles) and "mercy" since they are doing something wrong and we forbear. The person who needs the pity and is in a position to receive it (if their trials are understandable, say.) is "pitiable".

"Give a pass" and "let it slide" are both forms of "Excuse" (v), as well as examples of *being* "merciful", "understanding", "forgiving", and "magnanimous". (In archaic English, these could also be described as pitiful, but somehow pitiable and pitiful became synonyms.)

[Magnanimity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnanimity) is the elevated mind that accepts personal discomforts and such to make the world a better place. Having mercy on someone in a situation where people, as a rule, need such, certainly qualifies.

The "pass" itself *is* the "Excuse" (n).

Comment: I was a little confused by your answer but am mostly commenting on the word "pitiable".  I would have to think that someone who's "going through stuff" to the extent that they need a "bitch pass", would probably take offense at being considered "pitiable".  Maybe in my culture (US Midwest), being pitied is not a good thing.  Maybe we'd want to be understood or have someone's empathy but definitely not their pity.  That's an opinion and probably a good reason this question should be closed for being primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Pride doesn't change the fact that it is, literally and clearly, pity. Weakness pretty much always has negative connotations.  (Your suggestion of "empathy" should lead to the term "pathetic" were that not the case.) If someone is doing something wrong for understandable and forgivable reasons, that's still a bad thing. You do flag a point I missed: **nothing** is inoffensive to *every*one.

Comment: Put more briefly: if you don't want my pity, you don't want a/the "bitch pass", *either*, because it's the *same thing*.

Comment: +1 but I have corrected *forebear* to *forbear;* let us leave our ancestors out of this.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I clearly ought to spend more time proofing anything written on this phone.